# How do we OR filters using rethinkdb and nobrainer in ruby on rails?

Tags: rethinkdb-ruby

Following the nobrainer docs here:  http://nobrainer.io/docs/querying/

I am trying to do an OR query, to look for articles where a keyword matches the title or text fields...

The following query returns no results...

```
 s = 'something'
 @articles = Article.where(:or=>[:title=>/(?i)#{s}/, :text=>/(?i)#{s}/])
```

I checked my regex with the following query and it works...

```
 @articles = Article.where(:title=>/(?i)#{s}/)
```

Could someone help us understand how to do OR queries?  Thanks.

UPDATE:

The query returns results only if the search term is found in both fields... so it appears to be working like an AND instead of an OR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [nobrainer documentation](http://nobrainer.io/docs/querying/) warns of this behaviour:

> **`:or => [p1,...,pN]`** evaluates to true when at least one of the predicates is true.
>
> Be aware that **`[:a => 1, :b => 2]`** is the same as **`[{:a => 1, :b => 2}]`**, which is not the same as **`[{:a => 1}, {:b => 2}]`**.

Your query may work if you add some curly brackets:

```
 @articles = Article.where(:or=>[{:title=>/(?i)#{s}/}, {:text=>/(?i)#{s}/}])
```